Resolution and delta function
Any attempt to measure the value of a physical quantity is limited, by the finite resolution of the measuring apparatus used. on the one hand the physical quantity we wish to measure will be in general a function of an independent variable. on the other hand the apparatus we are using does not give the true output value of the function;a resolution function $g(y)$ is involved. means that the probability that an output value $y=0$ will be recorded instead as being $y$ and $y+dy$ is given by $g(y) dy$. To obtain a good result we wish the resolution function to be as close to a delta function I just didn't understand this from my book. I got some idea but I don't if im right.
So all measurements is a function of one are more independent variables makes sense but our measuring apparatus does not produce theoretical values? Is that what the lines above mean? And the resolution is a probability density function of errors? How can we possibly deduce a function for errors before even measuring the quantity? And what does that mean that the probability that the output $y=0$ will be recorded instead as being between $y$ and $y+dy$ is given by $g(y) dy$. Please Explain it to me

What author? What book and page number?

Please edit the question to include this information rather than placing it in the comments. This just helps he question be self contained.

A 'delta function' is actually a distribution (a generalized function)
that only can be computed in combination with an integration-over-a-range.
The delta distribution is an ideal one to represent a very accurate measurement, because repeating the measurement will always hit the
same value (the only value that is correct) if there  is no
randomness in the measurement.
That means that every large group of measurements of (for instance)
a weight will have very close agreement; the standard
weight is the definition of weight, it has a single value of
measure: that's a delta distribution.
Secondary standards of weight will be... close to a delta distribution.
Those secondary standards define a reality-based approximation to
the delta distribution.
To determine the errors in the secondary standards, one would
attempt to measure differences from the primary standard weight.
No finite accuracy possibility exists that they would be an
actual delta-distribution, but a histogram picture
will give a nearly-delta-function representation.   One
can approximate such a histogram with a function that is NOT
a 'generalized function'.
The approximate function is more convenient for calculation than
a histogram would be; you might only need to know the RMS deviation
in those secondary weights.

if I understand correctly sir what you are saying is the accurate measurements means measurements with No errors will have 0 standard deviation in the delta function but in reality due to the errors the measurements produce a distribution am I right sir?  But what does it mean that the probability the output y=0 will be recorded instead as being between y and y+dy given by g(y)dy?

@Hello -The 'g(y) dy' is the formula to integrate in order to calculate the probability of a measurement being between the integration bounds; in addition to having zero width, a delta-distribution is normalized so the integral from (- infinity) to (+ infinity) is one; that makes the delta-distribution hopeless as a calculable point-by-point function.

Yes sir it's a probability function but whats that mean? probability of the measurement is being between y and y+dy of the function g(y).but what does g(y) represents? Is it represent the error made by apparatus with each individual measurements? Is that why as long as the g(y) look like delta function which has very very small standard deviation so The error is minimum? And yes the probability to measure something is 1 but what does that have to do with zero. Does it mean the apparatus always have probability it takes a output zero? Even if the true function never does(if its error function)?

@Hello The 'delta distribution' gives a finite probability that a measurement error is zero.   That is not a realistic detail (it involves an infinite probability density in the function value), but is easy to calculate with.   More detailed error models, with a bell-curve shape (made likely due to the central limit theorem) are realistic, and have zero  probability of zero error because the integral has zero range of integration and a finite probability density everywhere.
